# How can I prevent Chrome from putting "Fwd: " in the subject line of emails?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

If I click File | Email Page Location, Chrome puts a totally obnoxious "Fwd: " in front of the page's title as the subject.

How can I make this stop?

Comment: grab Chromium sources and edit the code which does that. AFAIK there's no user configurable setting to remove that

Comment: Is Chromium any different from the publicly-available Chrome browser?

Comment: you'll lose out on Integrated PDF reader, Flash player, Print, Auto update and few others http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)#Differences_from_Google_Chrome

Comment: The **Fwd: ** should be there, it should be reserved for *forwarded* mail. Instead of editing the code yourself, you could open a bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: You're including web site links in the category of "forwarded mail"? No other browser (or user) that I've encountered prepends link emails with "Fwd: ".

Comment: You could probably make some sort of Greasemonkey/Tamper Monkey script to remove the "FWD".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: Install the ["Send this page as email" extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-this-page-by-google/dbeoemfhkdniadbojeencpkgmobndpai)**. It's made by google and you can use either your default email client or gmail to send the page.

It sends only a link to the page, and not the page contents, if this is not what you want surely there are other extensions that will send the page contents.

**Long answer**:

I found this conversation on [a developers mailing list for Chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29232#c1). It's dated from 2009 and states:

> Implement "Email Link To Page" menu command. **This menu item only
>   exists in the Mac build**(*), but the code is cross-platform so it could be
>   hooked up on other platforms as well, if desired. It works by
>   generating a URL of the form
>   mailto:?subject=Fwd:%20PAGETITLE&body=%0A%0APAGEURL and telling
>   platform_utils to open it.

(*) emphasis is mine.

So the "FWD" is builtin into Chromium's (and therefore, Chrome's) internal code, and is not caused by the email software.

You have the following options:

- Stop using Chrome.
- Look for a setting in Chrome to disable this. I do not own a mac so I can't say if there's a setting for this on the options page.
- If there's no setting to disable this, you can follow @MartínCanaval's suggestion and [register a new issue on Chromium's official project page](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).
- You can install an extension to send the page as email, one that doesn't prepend messages with FWD.

Comment: @ruda.almeida, I'm accepting this answer and switching back to Safari. Thanks for the in-depth answer.

Comment: why would you ever use safari?